# how to display all latest posts from multiblogs in wordpress home page

Tags: php, wordpress

how to display all latest posts from multiblogs in wordpress home page .It have only one config file, i have sone multiblog using network

Answer (score 1):

You could use get_last_updated and inside of each blog, use get_blog_post.
Codex:

- http://codex.wordpress.org/WPMU_Functions/get_last_updated
- http://codex.wordpress.org/WPMU_Functions/get_blog_post
- http://codex.wordpress.org/Category:WPMU

Comment: i need to display all latest posts and the author name from multiblogs in wordpress home page, using blog id.

Comment: Why not use this function? It is just for what you've asked.

Answer (score 0):

I thik this is what you are looking for

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-mu-sitewide-tags/